# How can I fix coordinates of vertices?

Tags: vertices, proportional-editing

When I use proportional editing, I want some vertices to be fixed at where they are.

If you know how to fix the global coordinates of vertices, can you please tell me?

Answer (score 2):

In the normal course of  editing, you can <kbd>H</kbd> hide elements you don't want to affect.

But then, you can't see them... So, if you want to, you can <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> make an instance of the object, left in Object Mode, so you can see what you're doing:

[image]

Comment: +1 didn't know that....that's genius ;) Love Blender! ;)

Comment: Thanks, @Chris! I have to say, though, I still prefer 3DS's fuss-free proportional (weighted) _selection_ , to Blender's Proportional Editing. It's much more flexible. That. and _Editable Mesh_ ( a snapshot) on the modifier stack. The rest, they can keep :)

Comment: I am sorry, I never worked with another 3D software than Blender - except while studying - but that was decades ago - so I cannot really compare…‍♂️

Comment: Thank you, @RobinBetts! Though I will still wait for further answers for a while, your answer was useful.